# Flex: Get an item from a AdvancedDataGrid given an index

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I've got a subclass of AdvancedDataGrid showing a tree-like data structure.  How can I, given the index returned by `calculateDropIndex`, get the item at that index?

After reading through reams of code, it seems like the least terrible way is:

```
var oldSelectedIndex:int = this.selectedIndex;
var mouseOverIndex:int = this.calculateDropIndex(event);
this.selectedItem = mouseOverIndex;
var item:* = this.selectedItem;
this.selectedIndex = oldSelectedIndex;
```

The other option seems to be tinkering around with the `iterator` property... But, judging by the way I've seen it used, that will get pretty harry pretty quickly too.

So, how can I get the item at a particular index in an advanced datagrid without going insane?

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
// Get the dropIndex from the dragEvent
var index:int = this.calculateDropIndex(event);
// Get the itemRenderer from the index
var renderer:IListItemRenderer = this.indexToItemRenderer(index);
// Get your item from the data property of the itemRenderer
var item:Object = renderer.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.dataProvider.getItemAt(calculateDropIndex(event));
```

Looking through the docs, it seems you may be able to use openNodes, which returns an Array of all open nodes, which should correspond with your index?

```
this.dataProvider.openNodes[calculateDropIndex(event)];
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work on hierarchical data. `this.dataProvider` is an instance of 'HierarchicalCollectionView', which doesn't have a 'getItemAt' method.

Comment: Is the index returned by calculateDropIndex the flattened index of the item? In that case, I suppose you would have to count which child it's pointing to... which I suppose isn't less hairy than what you're suggesting...